# Play framework 2.5.1 Environment variables and property substitution

Tags: playframework, properties, environment-variables, playframework-2.5

I want to set up a Play application within Docker and want to pass in DB connection parameters using properties and Environment variables.

Is the below way a valid way of doing it ?

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"

mongo-async-driver {
  akka {
    loglevel = WARNING
  }
}
mongodb {
  host = ${?MONGO_HOST}
  port = ${?MONGO_PORT}
  user = ${?MONGO_USER}
  pass = ${?MONGO_PASS}
  db = ${?MONGO_DB}
  uri = "mongodb://"${mongodb.user}":"${mongodb.pass}"@"${mongodb.host}":"${mongodb.port}"/"${mongodb.db}"?authMode=scram-sha1&rm.tcpNoDelay=true&rm.nbChannelsPerNode=10"
}

admindb {
  host = ${?MONGO_HOST}
  port = ${?MONGO_PORT}
  user = ${?MONGO_USER}
  pass = ${?MONGO_PASS}
  db = ${?MONGO_DB}
  uri = "mongodb://"${admindb.user}":"${admindb.pass}"@"${admindb.host}":"${admindb.port}"/"${admindb.db}"?authMode=scram-sha1&rm.tcpNoDelay=true&rm.nbChannelsPerNode=10"
}
```

I want to pass in following environment variables:

1. MONGO_HOST
2. MONGO_PORT
3. MONGO_USER
4. MONGO_PASS
5. MONGO_DB

and want the HOCON property replacement to construct the final uri and in code I will access it as mongodb.uri and admindb.uri to get final values.

Comment: So, what is exactly your doubt here? How to configure env vars using docker? How to refer to env vars using hocon?

Comment: Both, but I've already resolved it. It works the way I did it.

Comment: You can answer your own question. That would be useful for other users in future. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that the above method is the best way to pass environment variables into a Play Framework application.

If its a docker container, the environment variables can be passed in with
`-e KEY=VALUE` command-line arguments.

This can be used to provide a more dynamic nature to the application possibly for multi-tenancy or securely assigning DB credentials, etc.